# How to Find ColumnPostion by Text in SpreadsheetGear?

Tags: c#, spreadsheetgear

How to find Column Position from Header by using  text in Spreadsheet Gear?

i.e  want to find Remark Text ColumnPosition From SpreadSheet.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Got the result is as below.

```
SpreadsheetGear.IRange range = workbookView.ActiveWorksheet.Cells.Find("StringtoFind", null, SpreadsheetGear.FindLookIn.Values, SpreadsheetGear.LookAt.Part, SpreadsheetGear.SearchOrder.ByRows, SpreadsheetGear.SearchDirection.Next, true);
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You could loop though the columns in the header row until you find your text match.

```
//Get the cells of a worksheet
SpreadsheetGear.IRange cells = worksheet.Cells;

int iColRemark = 0;
//loop through columns
for (int iCol = 0; iCol < cells.ColumnCount; iCol++)
{
  //check header row for colummn that has the text 'Remark'
  if (cells[0, iCol].Text.Equals("Remark"))
  {
    iColRemark = iCol;
    break;
  }
}
```